# Javascript toString(36) in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a `php` way to do the below `javascript` code:

```
var val = 100;
val.toString(36);
```

I am trying to pass values that is generated via `javascript` and verify it with `php`.

**Update**

After googling this I think `php` `base_convert` is the way to go but I do not know what to use in the `frombase` and `tobase` params.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`base_convert` is indeed what you need. The $from_base is the base the original number is in (which is base 10) and the $to_base is what you want (which is base 36) so it goes like this:

```
$val = "100";
base_convert( $val, 10, 36 );
```